# Check if a value is in an array and then count the required values in another column

Tags: excel, formulas

I have a list of repeating values in column A which I need to summarise and score. I want to check if the value in column A is "A" and then count how many issues (Column G) there are. `X` gives 1 point, `Y` gives 2 points and `Z` gives 0 points:

[image: SO3396 785 question example]

Goal is for each unique Desk to have a score of the issues. The resulting values for this exemplary list are written in column J but it needs to be a formula.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

In J15 please try and copy down:

```
=COUNTIFS(G:G,"x",A:A,I15)+2*COUNTIFS(G:G,"y",A:A,I15)
```